# How to bound a sequence of function $(\pi{/2} - \arctan(nx))^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given $x \in (0, + \infty)$, compute

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}(\pi{/2} - \arctan(nx))^2 $$

I know that to apply Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem, it has to satisfy this condition $|f_n(x)| \leq g$

May I get any hint on how to bound this function $|f_n(x)|$?

Comment: The dominated convergence theorem applies to integrals. Unless you want to convert the above into an integral (which is possible) it doesn’t apply. If you have converged it into an integral over some $f_n$, you have to show us *what this $f_n$ integral is*.

Comment: But regardless; $\arctan$ is continuous. This problem does not require measure theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$${\pi\over 2}-\arctan(nx)=\int\limits_{nx}^\infty {1\over 1+ x^2}\,dx \le \int\limits_{nx}^\infty {1\over x^2}\,dx ={1\over nx}$$ In order to get a bound by one integrable function we apply the above  inequality for $n=1$ to obtain
$$\displaylines{\left ({\pi\over 2}-\arctan(nx)\right )^2 \le \left ({\pi\over 2}-\arctan (x)\right )^2\ \\ \le\quad \begin{cases} {\pi^2\over 4} & 0\le x\le 1 \\
{1\over x^2} & x>1 \end{cases}}$$

**Remark** As the sequence $0\le f_n(x)={\pi\over 2} -\arctan(nx)$ is decreasing, the monotone convergence theorem is more suitable than the dominated convergence one.

Answer (score 1):

For $x > 0$, $\arctan$ satisfies the functional equation
$$\arctan \frac1x = \frac\pi2 - \arctan x\tag 1$$  Hence, as $n>0$ and $x>0$:

$$\left(\frac\pi2 - \arctan(nx)\right)^2
\stackrel{(1)} = \arctan^2\left(\frac1{nx}\right)
< \frac 1{(nx)^2}\\
$$
where the inequality follows from $\arctan x < x$ for $x>0$.

The error made in the estimation is of order $(nx)^{-4}$ at most because $\arctan^2$ is an even function.